# Macbook Pro loses Internet constantly for a couple seconds

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, mac, macbook

My new Macbook Pro (13", i7, Early2015, OSX 10.11.4) is loosing its Internet connection every couple minutes. The WiFi itself stays logged in, but the internet connection is gone. After a short while it sometimes comes back. Usually I deactivate and activate the WiFi to make it work again. The problem occurs in every WiFi I log into.

I checked the Console and the following error is showing always when the Internet is gone:

```
send_datagram_available_ping: pid 468 failed to act on a ping it dequeued before timing out.
```

[image: Screenshot 1: Console Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot 2: Error Details]

I already tried to deactivate the "automatic brightness control" after finding a thread on the Apple dev forum. Did not help.

How can I need to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating from 10.11.4 to 10.11.5 the problem disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

try going to system pref - network
edit location from automatic
just create a new location(+). 
name it "test" let's say

then click done
then click apply in bottom right corner

try connect